# Cumulative count distinct for a period of 3 months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this sample dataset that describes a transaction fact table called transaction:

[image]

I need to write a query that gives this result:

[image]

The main goal is to calculate the number distinct of customers for each year, month.
So I think to make over partition function but I don't find the best function to use (UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) but I didn't find the solution to to my goal (result shown).

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data. We cannot copy or use data from a picture.

Comment: select year,
month,
count(distinct as customer_id)
from (
select 
year(transaction_year) as year
month(transaction_year) as month
customer_id 
from transaction
union all
select 
year(dateadd(month,-1,transaction_date) as year 
month(dateadd(month,-1,transaction_date) as month
customer_id
from transaction
union all
select 
year(dateadd(month,-2,transaction_date) as year 
month(dateadd(month,-2,transaction_date) as month
customer_id
from transaction
)data
group by 
year,
month

Comment: So my table in Sql server is similar tothe screenshot Excel and the goal is to calculate for each year , month : the number of distinct customer for the last 3 months . I can share you the dataset in excel

Comment: [Edit] any clarifications directly into your question. And we want your data as nicely formatted text, not images.

Comment: How can I share my sample data , i have a csv file that you can import easily in SQL SERVER

Answer (score 0):

I shared my solution that works fine for my business need  but i explain it to our example SampleData :

```
DECLARE @StartPeriodLast2Months DATETIME = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-15,GETDATE())),MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-15,GETDATE())),1, 0, 0, 0, 0)

,@EndPeriodINC_1 DATETIME = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-13,getdate())), MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-13,getdate())) ,DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-13,getdate()))),23, 59, 59, 59)

,@EndPeriodINC_2 DATETIME = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-13,getdate())), MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-13,getdate())) ,DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-13,getdate()))),23, 59, 59, 59)

select @StartPeriodLast2Months ,@EndPeriodINC_2

create table #KPI_last_3months (Year int, Month int,

Nbrcustomers_3months int)

SET @Counter=0

set @ind = -13

WHILE ( @Counter <= 12)

-- why <= 12 : my business need to count KPI in the last year started from Year(getdate()) -1

-- example today 2022-07-05 : last year for KPI : 2021-06-05 --> 2022- 06-05

-- and we start to calculate nbrcustomers for 2021-06 (inculdes 2021-04 , 2021-05, to 2021-06-30 : 3 months)

BEGIN

INSERT into #KPI_last_3months

SELECT year,

month,

COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id ) AS NbrCustomers_3months,

from

(

SELECT

YEAR(@EndPeriodINC_2) year

,MONTH(@EndPeriodINC_2) month

,customer_id

from sampleData)

WHERE

cast(date_transaction as date) >= @StartPeriodLast2Months

AND cast(date_transaction as date)< @EndPeriodINC_2

)

SET @Counter = @Counter + 1

set @StartPeriodLast2Months = DATEADD(month,1,@StartPeriodLast2Months)

set @ind = @ind + 1

set @EndPeriodINC_2 = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,@ind,getdate())), MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,@ind,getdate())) ,DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,@ind,getdate()))),23, 59, 59, 59)

END

select * from #KPI_last_3months
```